# Event Registration - Conditional fields

Tags: civievent

We have online registration for an event. The registration allows the main attendee to register additional participants. The main person and the additional participants have different registration options. I don't want to display the additional participant registration fees/info on the main registration form. I only want to display that on the 'Additional Participant' page. On the additional participant page, which is only displayed if the main participant indicates on the main page that they want to register more than 1 person, I only want to display the additional participant fees.

Right now, this is display on both pages:
[image]

How do I just display the Registration pulldown on the main page for the first attendee and just display the additional participant information on the additional participant page? Right now both blocks are displayed on both pages.

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.9 and Civi 5.4.1.

Comment: Hey Kim - what CMS are you using?

Comment: Wordpress 4.9.9

Comment: I'm wondering if Caldera Forms Civi integration can do this for events?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the easiest to work with, but you could do this with the [Profile Conditionals](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond) extension.

Comment: @kzburn you put a bounty on this after I posted this answer.  Could you please give an update on what about this doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't see your post before I added the bounty. You can still get the bounty. I'm looking at what you suggested now. I'm relatively new to civi so I have a bit to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: While I don't think you should need it for what you're attempting, note that I have an enhanced version of this extension available [on my Github](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.joineryhq.profcond/tree/dev).